# Android: Calendar integration with custom notifications

Tags: android, android-intent, calendar, notifications

I need to integrate, in my android application, a calendar from which i can set new event. 
I know that is possible call the android calendar (using intent), but what I need is slightly different, for this reason:

I need that when the time of the event is reached, some code is started, and no default notification occurs! In other words I want create a custom notification when alarm of event goes off. Maybe I need to use AlarmManager

How can I solve this problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your problem is that you need to launch some kind of intent at a specified time then you can use AlarmManager. It allows you to schedule your application to be run at some point. When an alarm goes off, the Intent that had been registered for it is broadcast by the system.

For More information about AlarmManager, you can check this link : [AlarmManager](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/AlarmManager.html)

Comment: Yes, `AlarmManager` will do the job. You can call new `Intent` and use it as a notification when the alarm goes off.

Comment: I can manage AlarmManager! My problem is another: I call calendar android and I set certain event. When the date of the event occurs I want that no standard notification is executed! I don't want the notification generated from the android calendar (I'm talking about application). I want use a custom notification when the event time is reached!

Comment: Hi @GVillani82.. How were you able to sort the issue with custom notification (and no default notifcation)? Need a similar functionality